# Determining whether a functor to set is a forgetful functor from the outside

Tags: category-theory

In many categories, $\mathsf{Ring}, \mathsf{Group}, \mathsf{Field}, \mathsf{Graph}, \mathsf{Top}$, the objects are sets endowed with some additional structure. They are [first-order structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)) in the case of the first four, but topological spaces are not first-order structures and I don't want to rule them out.

The arrows are generally things that preserve that structure, but I don't now how to make that precise. For example, only the first four have arrows that are homomorphisms, i.e. preserve positive literal first-order sentences with parameters. In $\mathsf{Top}$, though, the continuous maps *reflect* openness rather than preserving it.

Anyway, all of these categories have forgetful functors going to $\mathsf{Set}$ that strip away this additional structure when we consider what they do to individual objects.

Suppose we know in advance that $\mathcal{C}$ is a category whose objects are sets with additional structure.

It's trivial to determine whether a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is a forgetful functor if we can *peer inside $\mathcal{C}$*.

Can we determine whether a functor is a forgetful functor or not when we *can't* peer inside $\mathcal{C}$? For example, can forgetful functors be identified in the category of categories (assuming that $\mathsf{Set}$ is already distinguished)?

Comment: The category of sets is very homogenous.  Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category of "sets with additional structure" with "obvious" forgetful functor $F$, such that all $X\in\mathcal{C}$ have the same cardinality.  Then for all $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X\to Y)$ are in bijection, so any permutation of $F(\mathcal{C})$ defines a new functor to $\mathbf{Set}$ (I think?).  Do you consider that to be a forgetful functor?  If not, how could we possibly distinguish it without knowledge of $\mathcal{C}$?  (Maybe I don't understand the question.)

Comment: All your examples are faithful functors. It is often considered that faithful functors are, in general, functors that forget structure.

Comment: @JacobManaker, there's a good chance my question isn't coherent. My goal is to find a good way to talk about categories that look like categories of "sets with additional structure". Meaning, if I can pick out $\mathsf{Set}$ and have a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$, what constraints can I impose of $F$ to capture the intuitive idea that $C$ looks like a set with additional structure. Based on Zhen Lin's comment, insisting that $F$ is faithful does the trick.

Comment: Following @ZhenLin's example, are you familiar with [concrete categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) (see also [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category))? These are categories equipped with a faithful functor $U$ to $\mathsf{Set}$, which we think of as the "underlying set" functor. These are quite well studied (see Ademcek et al's _[The Joy of Cats](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/17/tr17.pdf)_ for instance) and have both algebraic and topological examples as special cases.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I have not heard of them. Thank you for the links. It's interesting that $\mathsf{hTop}$ isn't concretizable ... I'll have to read more about why that is.